# Angular - How to close/remove search input when input empty, click outside input element or press esc

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, dom

I have a search bar that displays results when fed with text input, the problem is:

1. the search results do not go away even if the input field/search bar is empty.
2. It does not close if I **press ESC or click outside** the search bar or search results. I have tried different things with renderer and host view, I can't make it work. If it was regular js, I'm sure I would have been to solve this. Angular just has too many special quirks, I need some help with this.

this is what the problem looks like: [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a3pF.png)

components.ts file (removed my failed attempts):

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Renderer2,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';

import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { CountryService } from '../services/country.service';
import { OneCountry } from '../country';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css'],
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  faSearch = faSearch;
  countries: OneCountry[] = [];
  searchTerm: any;
  cachedCountries: OneCountry[] = [];
  

  constructor(private countryService: CountryService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onKeyPressEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    this.getCountries();
  }

  getCountries(): void {
    this.countryService.searchCountries().subscribe({
      next: (countries) => (
        (this.countries = countries),
        (this.cachedCountries = this.countries),
        console.log(this.countries)
      ),
    });
  }

  search(value: string): void {
    this.countries = this.cachedCountries.filter((val) =>
      val.name.toLowerCase().includes(value)
    );
  }
}
```

This is the template file:

```
<div id="search-component" class="w-full md:w-[32rem] dark:bg-darkblue-100">
  <div
    class="w-full px-4 h-[53px] flex justify-around align-center shadow-md border rounded"
  >
    <figure class="w-1/6 grid place-items-center">
      <fa-icon
        class="text-darkblue-100 dark:text-white text-lg"
        [icon]="faSearch"
      ></fa-icon>
    </figure>

    <input
      class="w-5/6 h-full focus:outline-none dark:bg-darkblue-100"
      placeholder="Search for a country..."
      #searchBox
      name="searchTerm"
      id="search-box"
      (input)="search(searchBox.value)"
      [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"
      (keypress)="onKeyPressEvent($event)"
    />
  </div>

  <ul class="mt-0 pl-0 relative z-20">
    <li
      class="z-20"
      *ngFor="let country of countries | searchFilter: searchTerm; index as i"
    >
      <a
        *ngIf="i < 10"
        routerLink="/detail/{{ country.name }}"
        class="z-20 border border-t-0 inline-block w-full md:w-[32rem] p-4 rounded shadow hover:bg-darkblue-100 hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-white dark:hover:text-black h-12 box-border"
        >{{ country.name }}</a
      >
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Curious why you are using (input) and (keypress) - don't they more or less fire on the same event?

Comment: @Kinglish The keypress and input were a result of just trying different things and hoping one would stick, forgetting to remove the keypress. Took the advice in the answer and used observables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Angular has too many special quirks". The problem I'm guessing is that your not reseting this.countries back to `[]`. You could wire in a blur:

```
   <input 
      ...
      (blur)="onBlur()" />
```

And then in your class

```
onBlur(){
   this.countries = [];
}
```

You should really look into observables though, and as @kinglish mentioned in the comment you have an input and a keypress which is odd.

Comment: Thanks. This was good, but I did Switch to observables and used the filter method in the search service instead. 
The keypress and input were a result of just trying different things and hoping one would stick, forgot to remove the keypress.

Answer (score 0):

Got rid of most of the old stuff and switched to observables. Looks like this now:

Component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { CountryService } from '../services/country.service';
import { OneCountry } from '../country';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css'],
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  faSearch = faSearch;

 countries$!: Observable<OneCountry[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
  constructor(private countryService: CountryService) {}

  // Push a search item into the observable stream
  search(term: string): void {
    // if (term.length >= 3) {
    //
    // }
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.countries$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      // Wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering search term
      debounceTime(300),
      // ignore new term if same as previous term
      distinctUntilChanged(),

      // Switch to new search observable each time the term changes
      switchMap((term: string) => this.countryService.searchCountries(term))
    );
  }
```

Search Service:

```
 searchCountries(term: string): Observable<any[]> {
    const url = `${this.countriesUrl}all?fields=name`;
    if (!term.trim()) {
      // If not search term, return empty country list
      return of([]);
    }
    return this.http
      .get<Country[]>(url)
      .pipe(
        map((country) =>
          country.filter((val) => val.name.toLowerCase().includes(term))
        )
      );
  }
```

template:

```
<div id="search-component" class="w-full md:w-[32rem] dark:bg-darkblue-100">
  <div
    class="w-full px-4 h-[53px] flex justify-around align-center shadow-md border rounded"
  >
    <figure class="w-1/6 grid place-items-center">
      <fa-icon
        class="text-darkblue-100 dark:text-white text-lg"
        [icon]="faSearch"
      ></fa-icon>
    </figure>

    <input
      class="w-5/6 h-full focus:outline-none dark:bg-darkblue-100"
      placeholder="Search for a country..."
      #searchBox
      name="searchTerm"
      id="search-box"
      (input)="search(searchBox.value)"
    />
  </div>

 <ul class="mt-0 pl-0 relative z-20">
    <li
      class="z-20"
      *ngFor="
        let country of countries$ | async;
        index as i;
        searchFilter: searchTerms
      "
    >
      <a
        *ngIf="i < 10"
        routerLink="/detail/{{ country.name }}"
        class="z-20 border border-t-0 inline-block w-full md:w-[32rem] p-4 rounded shadow hover:bg-darkblue-100 hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-white dark:hover:text-black"
        >{{ country.name }}</a
      >
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Resource](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#search-by-name)